# Compiler options basic ./configure explanation

Tags: linux, cygwin, wget

recently, i try to compile a gnu wget from source code in cygwin environtment that pop-up error if `perl is not found`. otherwise, perl is installed both perl and perl5 on */bin/* but the wget is try search perl on */usr/bin*. i think i have missed basic ./configure to setup path executable. so my question is basic.

what is it all about options on below:

*

```
--bindir=DIR

--sbindir=DIR

--libexecdir=DIR
```

*

Thank you

Comment: Try `./configure --help`

Comment: #Elliot Frisch i stills don't understand the explanation about that 3 options on help. it just user executables, system executables, program excutables. which that point to perl path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These options specify directories where a software package being compiled is going to be installed. As far as I remember it doesn't deal with checks performed by configure. Make sure that `perl` is in `$PATH`. If nothing helps, try to locate the exact place in the configure script (usually it's robot-generated and not intended for human eyes, but afterall it's a shell script, and anybody can read it) and see what checks exactly are performed to locate `perl`.

**Update**: I have checked, the tests corresponding to perl look like this in `configure.ac` (which essentially is a "source code" for `configure`):

```
AC_PATH_PROGS(PERL, [perl5 perl], no)
AC_PATH_PROG(POD2MAN, pod2man, no)
```

This means that `PERL` with executable named `perl5` or `perl` (somewhere in `$PATH`) is checked, and then `POD2MAN` with executable `pod2man`. Carefully check the configure output and `config.log` file and see what tests have failed.

**Update2**: The third argument of the `AC_PATH_PROG` and `AC_PATH_PROGS` is [value-if-no-found](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/autoconf/autoconf_41.html). Also you may specify the fourth argument, `$PATH` for this particular check. Make sure that `configure` gets rebuilt after you changed `configure.ac` (usually it happens automatically, but may be performed by `autoconf` explicitly)

Comment: i look the source code same as you. but it stills generated no perl and podman is found. what the thirst line argument `no'? should i set it to yes? so it will auto finding perl?

Comment: "The third" line, you mean, `libexecdir`? `libexecdir` is a direrctory (usually `/usr/lib` or `/usr/libexec` in a typical Unix/Linux system) where "backend executable components" (not intended for an end user) of the package _being compiled_ reside. And no, perl-related checks of the `wget` package don't use this directory. Have you looked in `config.log` file? What are the last lines of the file?

Comment: i means, the configure ac_path_progs function argument. "no".

Answer (score 0):

> what is it all about options on below:
>
> ```
> *
>
> --bindir=DIR
> --sbindir=DIR
> --libexecdir=DIR
> ```

The first (bindir), is where binaries will be installed. For wget, that's (on my system) `/usr/bin`.

The second (sbindir), is where static binaries will be installed. You might set that to `/usr/sbin`.

The third (libexecdir), is where your runtime libraries are to be installed. That's usually `/usr/lib`.

In fact, usually you let `configure` set all three by using `--prefix`.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```